# PgAdmin 4 display -7 in timestamp with timezone column

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have set my timezone on Postgresql to UTC+07:00, I also double check with `SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');`

[image]

Golang select queries and return them to the front-end `+07:00` with no problem. But whenever I open pgAdmin 4, it always shows me -07, so I have to calculate +14 in my head

[image]

Comment: You didn't show the result of the settings query.

Comment: @jjanes As I said, it's just UTC+07:00

Comment: 1) See [POSIX Time zone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-posix-timezone-specs.html): *The positive sign is used for zones west of Greenwich. (Note that this is the opposite of the ISO-8601 sign convention used elsewhere in PostgreSQL.)*. 2)  a) Use an actual time zone not an offset. or reverse your sign.

Answer (score 0):

UTC+07:00 is a posix-style specification, and those count hours in the opposite direction as the normal specification.

Presumably golang overrides your setting with the one from its own environment.